# Does the following proof answer Chan's question he made on the 3/3/2011 'Is there an elementary proof of Fermat's last theorem'.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof by Contradiction of Fermat's Last Theorem
Proof for an Even Exponent

Step[i] Assume $C^n = a^n + b^n$ {equ.[1]}: exists for 4 natural / integer numbers $C, a, b, n$. and that  $C , a ,  b$ are co-prime to one another.

Step[ii] The difference of two squares is given by the well proven identity 
$x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)•(x - y)$ {equ.[2]}: Euclids Elements : Book 2 : proposition 5 & 6.

Step [iii] $x, y$ can be any of the infinity of the natural numbers / integers
so let $x = a^n$ and $y = b^n$. Therefore $(a^n)^2 - (b^n)^2 = (a^n + b^n)•( a^n - b^n)$ {equ.[3]}.

Hence $a^n•a^n -  b^n•b^n = C^n•( a^n - b^n)$ {equ.[4]}.

Step [iv] By the Distributive Law of Multiplication:
     $a^n•a^n -  b^n•b^n = C^n•a^n - C^n•b^n$ {equ.[5]}:  hence $C$ can be either (a) irrational or (b) an integer .
Case (a) In principal we can always obtain the nth root of any integer via logarithms as    follows:  $((a^n + b^n)^{1/n})^n = C^n$ {equ.[6]}: so that $C$ must be irrational when it is not an integer.
Case (b) By the Laws of Indices equation [5] can be restated to give:
    $(a•a)^n - (b•b)^n = (C•a)^n - (C•b)^n$  {equ.[7]}:.
    $(C•a)^n - (C•b)^n = ((C•a)^{n/2} + (C•b)^{n/2})•((C•a)^{n/2} - (C•b)^{n/2})$  {equ.[8]}:
but  $(C•a)^{1/2}$ and  $(C•b)^{1/2}$  would both be irrational and consequently so also would  be $(C•a)^{n/2}$   and  $(C•b)^{n/2}$ unless $(C•a)$ and  $(C•b)$ are perfect squares which   would mean that C = a and C = b which is a contradiction.
If the two terms are irrational then:
    [i] The sum and difference terms must also be irrational.
    [ii] The rectangular area formed by the product of their sum and difference would   also be irrational. But the area of the rectangle formed by {equ.[3]} is both rational and integer so the replacement of both $a^n$ and $b^n$ by a single integer $C^n$ has been demonstrated to be impossible as it is clearly a contradiction for the integers hence REDUCTIO AD ABSURDUM and which demonstrates that the equation:
    $C^n = a^n + b^n$  can never have an all integer solution when n is even and at  least one of the terms must be irrational.
    However since $(a^n)^2$ is always an even power function it does not address the case    of  $a^n , b^n , C^n$  when the exponent n is odd. i.e. $a^3, a^5, a^7, a^9, a^{11},...... .$

Proof for an Odd Exponent

Step[1] Assume $C^n = a^n + b^n$ exists for 4 natural / integer numbers $C, a, b, n$ and that $C, a,  b$ are co prime to one another. Rearrange to give $C^n - b^n = a^n$.

Step[ii] The difference of two powers can be restated as follows:
    $C^n - b^n = (C^{n/2} + b^{n/2})•( C^{n/2} - b^{n/2})$  {equ.9}: but $(n/2)$ is rational and not integer 
    [i.e. $3/2=1.5$]  when n is odd so that any term of the form $C^{n/2}$ will be irrational due     to the taking of the square root except when C is a perfect square when $C^{n/2}$  will then be an even function covered by the even proof.  Now all $a^n = C^n - b^n$  for $n>2$ can be described by a rectangle with integer sides:
     $[a^{n-m}]•[a^m] = (C^{n/2} + b^{n/2}•( C^{n/2} - b^{n/2})$ {equ.10}:.  But when $C^{n/2}$  and/or  $b^{n/2}$  are irrational then the product of their sum and difference is also irrational therefore it is a contradiction that $C^n = a^n + b^n$ can have an all integer solution when the exponent is odd hence REDUCTIO AD ABSURDUM.
Therefore the equation $C^n = a^n + b^n$ has no reality when all four variables are natural / integer numbers as Pierre De Fermat stated all those years ago.            Q.E.D.

Comment: The sum and product of irrationals is not necessarily irrational. E.g. $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2 = 2$, and $\sqrt 2 + (1 - \sqrt 2) = 1$.

Comment: still no reason to down vote. the question is a good one, independantly from the answer. (i dont mean you, joshua)

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert at this topic, but there are some obvious errors:

For the odd proof, "But when $C^{n/2}$ and/or $b^{n/2}$ are irrational then the product of their sum and difference is also irrational" does not always hold, as Joshua Pepper mentioned in $\sqrt2 \cdot \sqrt 2$, and for the even proof a similar fallacy occurs at "[ii] The rectangular area formed by the product of their sum and difference would also be irrational."

Comment: (Just pointing more fallacies) Something can be either **rational or irrational**, not **integer or irrational** (although in this case you can actually justify that if $a,b$ are both integer then $C$ can't be a fraction). Also, the negation of $(Ca)^{1/2}, (Cb)^{1/2}$ are both irrational is not that they are both rational. Also that $Ca$ is a perfect square does not imply that $C=a$. And the list continues..

Comment: Consider the irrationals $\sqrt {2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, multiplying their sum and difference gives the integer 1.